# Entity Framework, cannot delete record after just adding it

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm making a simple WPF application that uses one table in a DB. I'm using Entity Framework. Here's how I add my new record:

```
public static bool CreateNew(CustomerModel newCustomer) 
{
    var addCustomer = new Customer 
    {
        ID = newCustomer.ID,
        Name = newCustomer.Name,
        Address = newCustomer.Address,
        City = newCustomer.City,
        Country = newCustomer.Country
    };
    try 
    {
        //_context.Customers.Add(addCustomer);
        _context.Entry(addCustomer).State = EntityState.Added;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Works fine: record appears in DB.

Now I try to delete the record that was just added based on its `ID`:

```
public static bool Delete(long id) 
{
    var cust = new Customer() { ID = id };
    try 
    {
        _context.Entry(cust).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        /*_context.Customers.Attach(cust); 
        _context.Customers.Remove(cust);*/
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Doesn't work.

It seems like the DbSet within the application does not hold the entry that was added to the DB. How do I fix this?

PS. Customer class is my `POCO` entity and `CustomerModel` is the class I use for the application. `_context` references the `DbContext` Entity Framework uses

Comment: What about this? `var  cust = _context.Customers.Find(id); 
    _context.Customers.Remove(cust);`

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed

Comment: `DbContext` is not thread safe, you should create and instance each time you access the DB, and wrap it in a `using {...}` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead. Use [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx) method like this:

```
var cust = _context.Customers.Find(id); 
_context.Customers.Remove(cust);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I had been experimenting with the find method thinking that the problem was based on the new record not being in the cache, but only in the DB. So I had to fetch it before I delete it. Unfortunately I was passing the wrong parameters when I was experimenting, passing the Customer object I had initialized instead of the long value into the Find method. Thank you for this!